# Android 11 - What exactly does "allow background activity" do?

Tags: battery, android-11, background-process

From what I understand, it simply allows apps that are manually ran to update and send notifications faster while in the background. Is that all it does, and if so should you turn it off for most apps if it saves a good amount of battery?

Does not allowing background activity interrupt any other function of an app other than updates and notifications?

Edit: If you do disable it, will the app still start by itself to update regardless if you open the app or not and take up RAM?

Comment: Where did you find "allow background activity" setting? A screenshot will be helpful. Also mention your ROM/device.

Comment: Sounds more like a non-AOSP modification to disable the "feature" introduced with Android 11 that restricts what apps are allowed to start a background service.

Answer (score 2):

"Allow background activity", under Battery, refers to whether apps are allowed to run in the background (when you're not using them onscreen, or the app is not visible to you) or not. The battery optimization option that disables background activity just adds a control for apps that have been running for a long time in background aiming to save battery life.

If you want any app to keep running without restriction, you can remove it from the optimization list.

My answers source: [Source 1](https://forums.androidcentral.com/ask-question/967224-difference-between-optimized-battery-usage-allow-background-activity.html) and [Source 2](https://www.reddit.com/r/galaxys10/comments/ds3l2r/whats_the_difference_between_allow_background/). Also, [this link is for developers](https://developer.android.com/guide/background), but reading it might help you understand how the background apps actually behave and what can be considered background activity.

Also, I've just found this [link that explains how to deal with background apps and save battery](https://www.slashdigit.com/restrict-background-activity-in-android/). This can add some details on how that feature works and how to toggle it on/off.

In addition, the app doesn't actually stops running in background - this configuration prevents the app from using battery, [according to this link](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/save-android-battery-by-limiting-background-activity/). Quoting them:

> You've prevented that app from using your battery when it's not in use, but if you open up the application manager, you'll see that application might still be running in memory. To close the app, open the application manager and swipe the app from the list. This will close the app and prevent it from using your battery.

Comment: Thank you, though from my own experiment I still received notifications from gmail if I turned off "background activity" if I enable auto-sync, so the person said in source 2 is incorrect. It seems to "update" an app to send notifications faster. This seems to only apply to notifications like an alarm you set in the background, not the ones that come from remote sources.
What I'm wondering is does "allow background activity" only apply to apps that are in the app selector if off screen? I'm confused if there is a difference whether or not it works if the app is never opened in the day.

Comment: I've added some information that I hope it would clarify things for you. I have to confess, I've been also learning while researching sources about this topic :)

Comment: Thanks, no problem! From what I understand now even though background activity is turned off, the app can update and send push notifications but I think that's the extent of it.
Sleeping apps will put stop the background process of apps when not used, but allows it to be used when needed, just delayed. Optimizing apps will allow background usage, but will restrict some functions to a time similar to when they're "put to sleep."

Comment: Hello again, I was wondering if you knew what allowing background activity would do for gmail.
It seems that I still get notifications regardless as long as auto-sync is turned on, but I don't know what else it would really do.
If I was downloading a large file and went off-screen or closed the app, would that file continue to be downloaded without background activity enabled since it's kind of like an "Active" task? What would enabling this for gmail really do and is it helpful?

Comment: I've never tested it, but I believe once you started a download from an attachment in GMail, it will continue downloading if the app goes background even with background activity disabled.

Comment: I see, even if you close the app? I'm guessing downloads are managed by the system itself and not the app so I'm assuming yes.
Do you also know what exactly background activity being allowed would do vs when it's not on? My guess is you would only have the app load a bit slower when you first go back to it after a few minutes, other than that I see no use.

Comment: I believe when an app closes, it gently finishes what it is doing to close in a clean way - I mean, no partial downloads, no partial saves, no data loss and so on.

Comment: Ah, so it will most likely just finish downloading without interruption or do you mean it will cancel? Do you know what other uses background activity does for gmail or is it pretty much irrelevant?

Comment: I believe it will finish the download. I'm not sure of other uses background activity related to Gmail - there should be something related to send mail, upload attachments and so on, but I didn't test that...

Comment: Thanks, I don't think it has any use personally, just to load the app faster as it works in the background when you open it again. Apps like sleep cycle definitely need this function on so it can work without having to have the app on screen.